# verbose: Could not fetch session, since connecting socket has no cookie (is this a cross-origin socket?)

Tags: node.js, session, sails.js

Recently I am studying the sails js web framework. So I follow the guide of sails get-starting document. When I use the command of "sails new test", and as my expected, it generates a new web project which name is test. Then I input the command to lift the sails-"sails lift --silly", but when the web app lifted , it always report this information:

> "verbose: Could not fetch session, since connecting socket has no cookie (is this  a cross-origin socket?)"

I think this is a pure project which sails generate automatilly, it should not report this information, but I do not know why the console report this error?
Does anyone encounter this issue? and is it a normal case or not? if not, how can I solve this?

Comment: not seeing this on sails 0.11.2

Comment: This issue is not occuring in all environment, I just encounter it in my windows 7 desktop. I just hope to know why this issue.Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe it was caused by the database problem.